# iptables entry to log ip address on one side of bridge

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

I was wondering if anyone knew of an easy way to capture only the ip addresses on one side of a connection.  I have a transparent Linux bridge with iptables enabled so that I can do network accounting with iptables for traffic passing across the bridge.  However, I am doing this with an ipaddress for each host in the rules.  I want to script a way to make sure I have a rule for each host on one side of the bridge.  I know you can log ip data, but I was wondering if there was something available to just get a list of ip addresses, or maybe I am missing a way to do it in iptables.

Thank you for any ideas.

TonyZ

Answer (score 2):

Um, you mean iptables rules that will match the **physical interfaces** instead of the **bridge interface**?

```
iptables -A $CHAIN -m physdev --physdev-in $IN_IFACE -j $TARGET
```

Will that do?